# Running a standalone java file on android studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run the sample DeviceAdminSample.java file which is found in the android SDK sample in the path /ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/apis/app/DeviceAdminSample.java. I am able to open the file on Android Studio but I am not able to run it as it always runs my other projects. Is there a way to just run this java file by itself?

Answer (score 0):

An android project is comprised of more than just java classes. it requires a manifest and the various xml files for layouts etc. You should either open the example project and run it, or look at using the example code within your own app.

The fact that you're asking this question though indicates that you may find it more beneficial to do a few Android tutorials from scratch.